# How can I prevent the React build and npm from adding files to the project?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have Visual Studio 2019 Professional and we use Azure DevOps TFS for our source control. I am working on a brand new Asp.Net Core 5  app with React. There are two developers on this project including me. Somehow `./ClientApp/node_modules/` and `./ClientApp/build/` got placed in TFS. When I check in I have to exclude these two directories every time...

I have tried adding these two directories to a `.tfignore` in `ClientApp` but it seems these are ignored now. I have also marked both Hidden.

How can I prune these directories from TFS and prevent the build and npm from adding files back to the project?